# Can rtl8723ae card work with airmon-ng?

Tags: wireless, aircrack-ng

I have rtl8723ae wireless card. When I run:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

it tells me that the chipset is unknown:

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID     Name
3001        avahi-daemon
3003        avahi-daemon
3083        NetworkManager
3179        wpa_supplicant
3810        dhclient
Process with PID 5523 (dumpcap) is running on interface mon0
Process with PID 3810 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0


Interface   Chipset     Driver

mon0        Unknown     rtl8723ae - [phy0]
mon1        Unknown     rtl8723ae - [phy0]
mon2        Unknown     rtl8723ae - [phy0]
wlan0           Unknown     rtl8723ae - [phy0]
            (monitor mode enabled on mon3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chipset is unknown for `airmon-ng`, but as you can see this is not a problem, the monitor mode is enabled. So, `airmon-ng` works well with your network device.